# how to select this a Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have links like this :

```
<div id="section-1">
  <a class="a" href="#">somethig text</a>
  <a class="a" href="#">somethig text</a>
  <a class="a" href="#">somethig text</a>
  <a class="a" href="#">somethig text</a>
  <a class="a" href="#">somethig text</a>
</div>
```

Here goes JQuery:

```
$('.a').mouseover(function(){
 $(".a").animate({height:"100px"},150);
  $(".a").mouseout(function(){
   $(".a").animate({height:"30px"},150);
 });
});
```

I want to animate class a on mouseover but it animates all classes with name a , I want to animate exactly this a that is mouseovered

Comment: [Please read the jQuery tutorial on event handling](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/): *"In addition to the event object, the event handling function also has access to the DOM element that the handler was bound to via the keyword `this`. To turn the DOM element into a jQuery object that we can use jQuery methods on, we simply do `$( this )`"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use `stop()` before `animate()` because it stops the currently-running
>   animation on the matched elements.

```
 $( ".a" ).hover(function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({height:"100px"},150);
     }, function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({height:"30px"},150);
     });
```

Comment: Please explain your answer so that future visitors to this question will understand the solution you created.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$('.a').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "100px" }, 150);
});
$(".a").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "30px" }, 150);
});
```

Comment: One extra `mouseout` handler will be attached to `.a` every time `mouseover` event is triggered.

Comment: oh did not noticed the closing breaces are outside.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `this` in order to get the current element which is being hovered.

Try,

```
$('.a').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).animate({height:"100px"},150);
});

$(".a").mouseout(function(){
   $(this).animate({height:"30px"},150);
});
```

Or the preferred way is using `.hover()`,

```
$('.a').hover(function(){
   $(this).animate({height:"100"},150);
},function(){
   $(this).animate({height:"30"},150);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/674Nt/2/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$( ".a" ).mouseover(function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({height:"100px"},150);
     }, function() {
         $(this).stop().animate({height:"30px"},150);
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

by using `$('.a') you select every object with class a`

```
$('.a').mouseover(function(){
 //here this will refer to current a tag
 $(this).animate({height:"100px"},150);
});

  $(".a").mouseout(function(){
 //here this will refer to current a tag
   $(this).animate({height:"30px"},150);
 });
```